# Sort UICollectionView by Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, nsarray

My app includes a plist file that is my data for a UICollectionView.  The plist looks like this:
[image]

Here is my code for the collection view:

```
-(NSArray *)content {
    if (!_content) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask,
                                                             YES);
        NSString *plistPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myJournal.plist"];
        NSDictionary *help = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        _content = [help allValues];
        _titles = [help allKeys];
        NSLog(@"CONTENT%@", _content);
    }
    return _content;
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
       return [self.content count];
}
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[self.titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"MMMM";
    NSString *monthString = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] capitalizedString];

    dateFormatter.dateFormat=@"dd";
    NSString *dayString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

    CVCell *cell = (CVCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    [cell.labels setText:[[self.content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"verse"]];
    [cell.month setText:monthString];
    [cell.day setText:dayString];

    return cell;
}
```

Here is how the view looks:
As you can tell, it's not QUITE the way I would like it to lay out.  I would prefer either in order from left to right and top to bottom, or newest entries first, but I can't QUITE get it.  Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

UPDATE:

I have added an NSArray and use that to get the data from plist first, and then use an NSSortDescriptor to get the `_content` array created.  In the NSLog, it shows it in the order I want, but the end result doesn't change:

```
-(NSArray *)content {
    if (!_content) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask,
                                                             YES);
        NSString *plistPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myJournal.plist"];
        NSDictionary *help = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        _sortedArray = [help allValues];
        _titles = [help allKeys];


        NSSortDescriptor* nameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"theDate" ascending:NO];
        _content = [_sortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSortDescriptor]];
        NSLog(@"%@", _content);
    }
    return _content;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this. One is to setup your plist to contain an array instead of a dictionary at the root level (see screenshot). This makes sure that you preserve the order of the items (a dictionary has no order).

[image]

Another way is to order the items based on the key. You can do this as follow:

```
-(NSArray *)content {
    if (!_content) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                             NSUserDomainMask,
                                                             YES);
        NSString *plistPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myJournal.plist"];
        NSDictionary *help = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        _titles = [help allKeys];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";

        NSArray *sortedTitles = [_titles sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {

            NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj1];
            NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:obj2];
            return [date1 compare:date2];
        }];

        _sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSString *title in sortedTitles) {
            [_sortedArray addObject:[help objectForKey:title]];
        }
        _content = _sortedArray;
        NSLog(@"%@", _content);
    }
    return _content;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I have changed some of the stuff in code based on the link for sort descriptors, please see above for the edit...it still isn't changing the order at all.  I had tried changing the root from dictionary to Array, but doing that completely blanked out the entire view.

Comment: Do you have a 'theDate' key in all the dictionaries which also contains the date?

Comment: Try sorting it with the new code I've added to the answer.

Comment: It kind of gets there.  With that, from left to right and top to bottom I get:

19 18 17
16 15 14
20

Where 19, 16, and 20 are the starts of each of the 3 rows.

Comment: I have updated it now to convert it to a date before sorting, is it any different?

Comment: That did it.  I edited code a little bit to add in the _sortedArray

Answer (score 1):

Don't store your data as a dictionary. Dictionaries are inherently unordered collections. Make it an array of dictionaries, sorted by date.

Once you have an array of items, you can fetch it in sections and rows using:

### Edit:

In Objective-C

```
NSInteger columns = 3;

NSInteger numberOfSections = (NSInteger) ceil( count/(double)columns));

NSInteger indexOfCell = indexPath.section * columns + indexPath.row;
```

In Swift

```
let columns  = 3

let numberOfsections = Int(ceil(Double(array.count) / Double(columns)))

let indexOfCell = indexPath.section * columns + indexPath.row
```

Columns would be the number of columns in your collection.

`numberOfSections` would be the total number of sections in your collection. You'd return that in your `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` function.

`indexOfCell` would give you an index into your array of objects based on the requested section and row. You'd use that to fetch an object in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function.

Alternately, you could store your data as an array of arrays of dictionaries, where the outer array is your sections, the inner array is the rows for each section, and each dictionary would be the data for that cell.

Comment: Changing from Dictionary to Array for the root completely removes everything from the collection view.  Also, I'm not very familiar with Swift so reading that syntax is a little difficult.  You may have been typing this out while I made an update to the code in which I tried using a NSSortDescriptor, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: "Changing from Dictionary to Array for the root completely removes everything from the collection." Then you have a bug in your changed code. Dictionaries are not a suitable structure for the model for a collection view or table view because dictionaries are unordered collections. The code I typed out was in Swift (sorry, I didn't notice that your code was in Objective-C) but the concept is the same.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I provided an Objective-C version of my suggestion